# Allow access to local mongodb database to a different network

Tags: windows, tcp, port-forwarding, mongodb, tunneling

Is it possible to do tcp port forwarding using windows settings without having to access router settings? I am trying to give access to my local mongodb database to someone on a different network to collaborate and work with the same database. Switching to a cloud service like mondb atlas is not something I want to do and it is my last option.

Comment: If you're behind a NAT router, no.